# When the answer to a question has changed

Tags: discussion, answers

We have a question on [the longest flight](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/5065/what-is-the-longest-passenger-flight-with-a-flight-number-in-the-world).

This week, a new flight, QF8, from Sydney to Dallas 'took flight'.  It's the new longest in the world, according to the linked wiki and news reports.

I went to the question to add an answer, but it's ... awkward. Should I add a new one, and unaccept the other one. They'll seem strange having so many upvotes and yet the 'wrong' answer.

I feel we should have a consensus on how to handle this, moving forward.

Comment: Is making the whole thing community wiki an option?

Comment: Related: *[How might we cope with answers that change over time?](http://meta.travel.stackexchange.com/questions/50)* and the older *[Are questions that will go out of date “on topic” for this site?](http://meta.travel.stackexchange.com/questions/10)*.

Answer (score 8):

I think adding and accepting a new answer is perfectly fine. Editing your own answer is also completely fine (possibly keeping the old one below the new one). In some cases, asking a new question might also be an option.

Slight changes to an existing answer should be OK too but I would be wary of editing someone else's answer in place, if you are essentially providing a completely new answer. Unfortunately, if the OP is not there anymore to take care of his or her question, it might mean that [an incorrect answer remains the most prominent](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/13183/about-schengen-90-180-rule) and that's far from ideal.

Comment: if that answer is indeed incorrect, it's worth commenting on it, and voting it down.

Comment: @MarkMayo I did comment (but did not downvote as I don't think it's fair). It does not solve the accepted answer aspect.

Answer (score 1):

If the original answer was valid and correct, then just update it to continue to be valid and correct.

Optionally, add the new info while retaining the entire old answer below (or above, or whatever is appropriate).

Comment: That would work for small changes or for your own answers but if the old text is not relevant anymore, editing it in place would mean taking over the signature and votes while effectively providing a completely new answer. Feels a bit strange.

Comment: @Relaxed: A fair point, although in this particular case, the accepted answer is thorough enough that it would be appropriate to add a bit of new info while minimally editing the exiting info.